# How to remove remaining whitespace after a flex element wrapped below?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace

I have an inline-flex element containing badges with little information.
The goal is to keep the button always visible but wrap the badges on smaller devices one by one.

I want the button to always stick to the last badge.

The problem is, that when a badge wraps down and disappears, it leaves some white space or struct between the remaining visible badges and the button.

How can I remove this space just using pure CSS?

```css
.badges {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  /* creates space for the button */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.badges .badge {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.badges button {
  width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="badges">
  <div class="badge">FooBar 418$</div>
  <div class="badge">Baz 132$</div>
  <div class="badge">BarFoo 321$</div>
  <div class="badge">Qux 500$</div>
  <button>Find out more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `flex-grow: 1;` on `.badge` to tell it to take up all of the available space.

```css
.badges {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  /* creates space for the button */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.badges .badge {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

.badges button {
  width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="badges">
  <div class="badge">FooBar 418$</div>
  <div class="badge">Baz 132$</div>
  <div class="badge">BarFoo 321$</div>
  <div class="badge">Qux 500$</div>
  <button>Find out more</button>
</div>
```